# Random char* args[] to pass to execv

Tags: c, pointers, random, exec

I need to create a char* array[] that i then have to pass to execv.

- the first element would be the path "./exec_test"
- for the second argument: pick randomly between A/B
- for the third argument: pick a random letter A - Z
- for the fourth argument: pick random integer between [2, 2+A_CONST]
- Then NULL

  ```
  void perform_exec(){
      char *type= 'A' + (random() % 2);
      char *name= 'A' + (random() % 64);
      int rand_num= rand(); 

      char *args[5];
      args[0]= "./test_exec";
      args[1]= name;
      args[2]= type;
      args[3]= rand_num;
      args[4]= NULL;

      execv(args[0], args);
      printf("you souldn't see this. exec error\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  ```

  }

I know there is something terribly wrong with this code, but can't actually figure out what it is.

i get Error #014: Bad address.

Comment: assigning an `int` to `char*`..not a good way to go. Well yes do you think those addresses are accessible? `0` to `RAND_MAX`?

Comment: Pump up the compiler's warning level and take its warning(s) serious.

Comment: "*can't actually figure out what it is*" so what about learning C then?

Answer (score 1):

**`i get Error #014: Bad address.`**

The error message is very clear that your program is attempting to use an invalid address.

`errno` 14 represents `EFAULT`.

From [execve](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve)

> EFAULT
>
> filename points outside your accessible address space.

Your program is throwing this error because of these statements:

```
args[1]= name;
args[2]= type;
args[3]= rand_num;
```

Here `args` is of type `char (*)[]`, which is array of `char` pointers.
So, you are assigning integral type values to `char` pointers and compiler must be giving **warning** for this.

`execv()` access the arguments passed to it and it is giving `Bad address` error because it is considering the `args[1]` (`name`), `args[2]` (`type`) and `args[3]` (`rand_num`) as addresses and trying to access values at those addresses which is invalid.

You can do:

```
void perform_exec(){
    char type= 'A' + (random() % 2);
    char name= 'A' + (random() % 64);
    int rand_num= rand();

    char *args[5];
    args[0]= "./test_exec";

    args[1] = malloc (2 * sizeof(char)); //2 as it is either A or B
    args[1][0] = type;
    args[1][1] = '\0';

    args[2] = malloc (2 * sizeof(char)); //2 as it is a character
    args[2][0] = name;
    args[2][1] = '\0';

    args[3] = malloc (11 * sizeof(char)); //11 as INT_MAX is having 10 digits
    snprintf (args[3], 11, "%d", rand_num);

    args[4]= NULL;

    execv(args[0], args);
    perror("execv failed:");

    free(args[1]);
    free(args[2]);
    free(args[3]);

    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

---

Additional:

When you are running your program, you must be getting same values for `type`, `name` and `rand_num`. You might want to change the random number every time you want to run your program and to do so use [srand()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/) and [srandom()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/srandom).

Comment: `sizeof (char)`  equals 1 by definition.